# Using Ampersand character to create shortcuts on mac using Qt Designer

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-designer

I am currently working through a tutorial on designing a GUI using Qt Designer 5 in conjunction with Pycharm 3.4 on Mac Yosemite.

According to the (windows-based) tutorial preceding the text property of a line edit widget with the ampersand character causes the first character of the line edit text to become a shortcut.

When I convert the Qt Designer code to python using the pyuic4 utility and import this into my program it appears not to work.

Any advice as to what might I might be doing wrong would be most appreciated.  Thanks in advance….

```
def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "&Number Of Items", None))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "&Discount Percentage", None))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "&Price per Item", None))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Calculate Amount", None))
```

Comment: "not to work" is too vague. Is there an error? If so, post it.  What did you expect to happen that did not, what did happen instead?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [`QShortcut`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qshortcut.html#details), ampersand shortcuts are disabled by default on Mac. However, apparently it's possible to be enable them like this:

```
    QtGui.qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic(True)
```

I should also point out that your description of ampersand shortcuts in labels is wrong. A label must have [a buddy set](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#setBuddy) in order for its shortcut to transfer focus to another widget (such as a line-edit). This can be done in Qt Designer via its [Buddy Editing Mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-buddy-mode.html).